# Is there a good open-source MongoDB Queue Implementation for the C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, message-queue, mongodb-.net-driver

Not that it wouldn't be easy (or fun) enough to write one, it makes sense not to re-invent the wheel so to speak. I've had a look around at various attempts, but I don't seem to have yet come across an implementation that supports these criteria;

Simple queue OSS system with MongoDB persistence;

- C# Driver (official) based (so full POCO serialization)
- Tailable cursors rather than polling
- handles message timeout (GC correctly)
- handles consumer failure (ideally crash detecting re-insertion, but timeout with delayed re-insertion is fine) so findAndModify on complete
- multiple writers, multiple consumers
- threadsafe

Nice to have;

- allows for (latest only) message (replace older messages in the Q)

If anyone has nice simple a library like that floating around on GitHub that I've not yet found, please speak up!

Answer (score 0):

There's my little project - a  .net message bus implementation that works with MS SQL queues or MongoDB (MongoDB support is a recent addition). Link: http://code.google.com/p/nginn-messagebus/ and http://nginn.org/blog for some examples.
I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, it's also lacking in documentation and example departments and it doesn't exactly match your specs (polling instead of tailing) - but maybe it's worth giving a try. This is a publish-subscribe message bus, like NServiceBus or MassTransit - not a raw message queue.

PS I'm afraid there are mutually exclusive requirements in your specs: you can't use tailable cursor with concurrent consumers because you lose atomicity. If you want to tail a queue you should use only a single consumer.

Comment: Actually, you're probably right. Polling vs Tailing is a comparatively small compromosise if you want multiple readers. For many implementations though a single reader is probably the right architecture in any case, you just have to make sure the reader process gets recycled if there's an error. Probably a good thing to use idempotent messages (allows for at-least-once semantics) and use a message timeout probably combined with a process recycling and a message retry count.